# How to track github usage across the Enterprise?

Tags: github, github-enterprise

I am looking to track the feature adoption/GitHub usage.. etc. Looking for some kind of metrics or reports from github enterprise

Answer (score 2):

Found this site helpful which gives the metrics and tracks the usage of GitHub adoption- https://githubsmartboard.azurewebsites.net